# one signal code notificition not work in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-notifications, onesignal

i use one signal to send notificition vai firebase

i added this code to mainactivity

```
 // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
      OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
     
      // OneSignal Initialization
      OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
        .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
        .init();
```

and it work
but i create bottomnavigation bar witf fragments
and the notifiction now didnt work
i tried added it to TrackFragment.java but it didnt work

this is TrackFrgament

```
package mypacgae.name.com;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link TrackFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class TrackFragment extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout eLinearLayout;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment TrackFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static TrackFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        TrackFragment fragment = new TrackFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public TrackFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_track, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        eLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.LinearWebView);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipeweb);
        webView.loadUrl("the url of webview no need to show it");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return false;
            }


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                eLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        // pull to refresh
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        webView.loadUrl("the url . no need to show it");
                    }
                }, 1500);
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
        );



        return v;
    }

}
```

and this mainactivityt

please help and thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make application class in your main package:

```
class ApplicationClass : Application() {
   override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
        .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
        .init()
   }
}
```

then declare it in your manifest then try :

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".ApplicationClass">
```

and make sure you implemented the libraries and manifest placeholders well in your build.gradle:

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.codediversity.doodhwale"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0.5"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [
            onesignal_app_id: '4xxxxxxx4-8bcd-xxxxx-8c6d-3xxxx7155d',
            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
            onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
    ]
}

implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.15.0, 3.99.99]'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

Comment: in your main package

Comment: you can make new class in your main package because we need application class to declare it in manifest